# Does the antiderivative exist?

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

given the function $ 
     f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{0} 0, & x\leq 0 \\
         1, & x>0\end{array}\right. .
  $

then $ 
     F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{0} 0, & x\leq 0 \\
         x, & x>0\end{array}\right. .
  $

is an antiderivative, since $F'(x) = f$.

Some fellow students doubt this result.

What do you think:

a) is $F$ an antiderivative and
b) if not does $f$ has an antiderivative and
c) what is $F$?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Note that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ except at $x = 0$. So ...

Comment: Your function $F$ is not differentiable at $0$. There are more general notions of derivative, such as the weak or distributional derivative. Those derivatives don't give you functions in the normal sense, but the weak derivative of $F$ is basically $f$.

Comment: f has no primitive (antiderivative) on the entire real line because of Darboux's theorem about intermediate values.

Comment: The function $F$ is continous over the reals, but its derivative has a discontinuity at $x=0$ so it matches that of $f$. That said, it is not necessarily true that $f$ has an antiderivative due to the lack of continuity over the domain